# Google Script in Sheets - How to calculate with row values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've built a script which grabs (public) data from Instagram, dumps it in a table and then I construct a dashboard based on it.

It looks like this:

[image]

Now, I've built a formula that calculates the daily new followers if there is a value filled in:

```
=if(B3<>"",B3-B2,"")
```

However, in my script I use sheet.appendRow to (job-based) auto-populate the spreadsheet with new data every night at 12. The issue I have is that when I drag my formula down, say 20 lines to not have to go in everyday to drag down the formula), my  sheet.appendRow will paste it below those 20 lines (which essentially, are visually blank).

I've been looking around on Google (and stack) to find a function that can do the same as my formula, and will calculate the new daily followers every time at night (when the job runs), but my knowledge of Scripting is to limited to find a solution that works. So basically: the value from the current row in column B - the value from the row above in column B = New Daily Followers.

**I prefer to solve this with a Google Script**, as I'm looking to do additional calculations on other columns in a similar fashion, and can then just adapt the script to calculate these new KPI's.

Can anyone assist me in creating this?

Answer (score 0):

Apend in C1:

`={"Header" ; " " ; FILTER(B3:B-B2:B,A2:A<>"")}`

and delete all other formulas from column C.

Notes:

- The formula will create the filter and it's no need to drag down, will adjust automatically.
- assumed all cells from A2:A have go blanks inside the table
- `"Header" ; " "` to leave C2 blank

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the swift answer! That works, but ideally I would want the result to only start on C3, and C2 be blank. Because with this formula (pasting it in C1) will get me the result of B3-B2 in cell C2, which is not ideal.